# No indicator is suitable when titrating weak acid with weak alkali

Tags: acid-base, ph, titration

This was a statement in my book:

A solution of a weak acid cannot be titrated with a weak base using an indicator to find
the end-point because **the pH change is too gradual close to the equivalence point.**

Could someone please elaborate the bold text.

Comment: Check [this link](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/acidbaseeqia/phcurves.html) and search for the section "Titration curves for weak acid v weak base". Be sure to click on the "indicator" link in the section's note, too. Does that help?

Comment: if there is a weak base and a weak acid, there will be at least two pKs, complicating the titration curve.  The full pH range may be unobtainable by adding a weak base.

Answer (score 6):

An indicator works when the solution's pH is in its range. It's not necessarily the equivalence point.  The point is called the end point where it actually changes color.

If the difference in volume is small between the equivalence and end points, then the indicator can be used.  Since a gradual change implies more volume must be added to obtain the same pH change in other acid base titration, the difference between equivalence point and end point(if you use indicator) will be more and therefore indicator will not be suitable for it.